# To convert a ethereum_types::H256 to String in Rust

Tags: rust, string-conversion

when I tried to convert  **ethereum_types::H256** to **String** by using to_string()

```
use ethereum_types::H256;

fn main() {   
    let s = H256::zero();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

I expect output to be

```
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

but output is

```
"0x0000…0000"
```

Answer (score 6):

This (weird) behaviour comes from the `fixed-hash` crate.

It implements several formatting traits:

- `Display` [which always elides the middle of the hash](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-common/blob/cd0fe159c8cb26b1c855e9f110aecd4bf4a40a24/fixed-hash/src/hash.rs#L231).
- `Debug` [which is equivalent to `LowerHex` alternate mode](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-common/blob/cd0fe159c8cb26b1c855e9f110aecd4bf4a40a24/fixed-hash/src/hash.rs#L221).
- `LowerHex` and `UpperHex` [which never elide](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-common/blob/cd0fe159c8cb26b1c855e9f110aecd4bf4a40a24/fixed-hash/src/hash.rs#L239-L261)
  .

Therefore, to get the output you want, use `LowerHex` with alternate mode:

```
    println!("{:#x}", s);
```

(alternatively you can use `Debug`, but the output of `Debug` should generally not be relied upon)

Comment: it gives error that the trait `std::fmt::LowerHex` is not implemented for `std::string::String`

Comment: Have you called `to_string` on your hash? Note that I have also edited it out of your question, because it is never necessary to call `to_string` with the `format!` family of macro. `to_string` is always equivalent to `Display`, but calling `to_string` and then passing the result to a `format!` macro is less efficient. It also prevents you from using traits other than `Display`.

Comment: yes, I have used `to_string` . My  final aim is to convert `s` to string and write it into .csv file but when i did it write   `"0x0000…0000"` to my file.

Comment: I suggest your read [the documentation of the `fmt` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html). You do not need to use `to_string`.